# How to preserve arguments after calling a function in POSIX

Tags: linux, bash, posix

In order to reuse some code and fragment my script I have a function to check some conditions and add arguments to script execution. However, after the function finish the arguments set there are not preserved.

Here is a simplify example of my intention:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

TARGET_FILE="${ENV}.env"

addEnvFile() {
    if [ -f "$TARGET_FILE" ]; then
        set -- "-env=${TARGET_FILE}"
        echo "ARGUMENTS: $*"
    fi
}

sampleFn() {
    # I need the arguments set in the "addEnvFile" function
    echo "CURRENT ARGUMENTS: $*"
}

addEnvFile
sampleFn "$*"
```

My goal is to have the argument from "addEnvFile" function (`-env=dev.env`) available to execute commands inside the `sampleFn`

Comment: `set --` inside a function will modify its own arguments, not the caller's ones.

Comment: yes, that's also my understanding, and that's why I'm asking "how" to do it, maybe there is some other workaround

Comment: Well, the work-around would be to just use `[ -f "$TARGET_FILE" ] && set -- "-env=${TARGET_FILE}"` in the main script, then call `sampleFn "$@"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `addEnvFile()` just echo the args and call it with `set -- $(addEnvFile)`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

TARGET_FILE="${ENV}.env"

addEnvFile() {
    if [ -f "$TARGET_FILE" ]; then
        echo "-env=${TARGET_FILE}"
    fi
}

sampleFn() {
    # I need the arguments set in the "addEnvFile" function
    echo "CURRENT ARGUMENTS: $@"
}

set -- $(addEnvFile)
sampleFn "$@"
```

```
$ file dev.env 
dev.env: empty
$ ENV=dev ./args.sh 
CURRENT ARGUMENTS: -env=dev.env
```

Note that I also changed `"$*"` to `"$@"`, so that it works correctly if you have multiple arguments.

Comment: thanks! that's actually an interesting workaround!